# How to change binding name on WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, wcf-binding

I need to change the green section in the WSDL of my service (binding:"tns:OpeInPort" to binding:"tns:OpeInPort**Binding**"):

[image: binding]

My Web.config:

[image: web.config]

Comment: How about you just change name of  endpoint `OpeInPort` to `OpeInPortBinding` in web.config?

Comment: if i change the name to the "endpoint", then my wsdl is:
<wsdl: port name="OpeInPortBinding" binding="tns:OpeInPortBinding"> 

This is my problem that they shouldn't be the same